# Correlation coefficient ρ of variables Y i Z

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, correlation, density-function

Random variabe $ X $ has discrete uniform distribution $ P(X=i) = {1 \over{100}} , i \in \{1,2,...100\}$.

Let random variables $ Y $ and $ Z $ be defined by

$ Y = 1 $ when $2|X$ or $3|X$. Otherwise $Y = 0$.

$ Z = 1 $ when $3|X$. Otherwise $Z = 0$.

Find correlation coefficient $p$ of variables $Y$ and $Z$.

I know that $p = {E [(Y - E(Y))(Z - E(Z)) \over { \sqrt{V(Y)V(Z)}}} $, but I have know idea how to find out density or distribution of $Y$ and $Z$ needed to calculate the correlation coefficient of this variables.

Comment: $Y$ and $Z$ are discrete, so do not have a density but a probability mass function. Actually the most simple non-trivial probability mass functions. This because both random variables only take values in $\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$Y$ and $Z$ only take values in $\{0,1\}$ so that:$$\mathbb EY=0\cdot P(Y=0)+1\cdot P(Y=1)=P(Y=1)$$and likewise $\mathbb EZ=P(Z=1)$.

Further $Y=Y^2$ and $Z=Z^2$ so above we also found $\mathbb EY^2$ and $\mathbb EZ^2$.

Then variances can be found on base of the rule $\mathsf{Var}(X)=\mathbb EX^2-(\mathbb EX)^2$.

Now it remains to find the covariance.

We can apply $\mathsf{Cov}(Y,Z)=\mathbb EYZ-\mathbb EY\mathbb EZ$ and already have $\mathbb EY\mathbb EZ$ so it remains to find $\mathbb EYZ$.

Now again note that $YZ$ only take values in $\{0,1\}$ so that $\mathbb EYZ=P(YZ=1)=P(Y=1\wedge Z=1)$.

Comment: so, $ E(Z) = P(Z=1) = { 33 \over 100} $ ? Because we got 100 numbers and $Z = 1 $ only then when the number is $3|X$, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot! :)